# My php will not send the details of the contact form to my email

Tags: php, html

Below is the php, and html I have but it does not send the info to my email. I feel like it has something to do with my setup in the php.ini file. I'll include my edit as well. If you have any ideas it would be greatly appreciated!

In the php.ini modified the following:

SMTP = outlook.office365.com

sendmail_from = email@mydomain.com

html:

```
<form method="POST" action="email-sender.php" id="contact-form-with-recaptcha" class="margin-clear" role="form">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="name">Name*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="">
        <i class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="email">Email*</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="subject">Subject*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="">
        <i class="fa fa-navicon form-control-feedback"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="message">Message*</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" id="message" name="message" placeholder=""></textarea>
        <i class="fa fa-pencil form-control-feedback"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button btn btn-default">
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', 0));
header('Content-type: application/json');

$Recipient = 'email@mydomain.coom'; // <-- I had put my email here

if($Recipient) {

    $Name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $Email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $Subject = filter_var($_POST['subject'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $Message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $Email_body = "";
    $Email_body .= "From: " . $Name . "\n" .
                   "Email: " . $Email . "\n" .
                   "Subject: " . $Subject . "\n" .
                   "Message: " . $Message . "\n" .

    $Email_headers = "";
    $Email_headers .= 'From: ' . $Name . ' <' . $Email . '>' . "\r\n".
                      "Reply-To: " .  $Email . "\r\n";

    $sent = mail($Recipient, $Subject, $Email_body, $Email_headers);

    if ($sent){
        $emailResult = array ('sent'=>'yes');
    } else{
        $emailResult = array ('sent'=>'no');
    }

    echo json_encode($emailResult);

} else {

    $emailResult = array ('sent'=>'no');
    echo json_encode($emailResult);

}
?>
```

I thought this would work but I may have made a mistake. Please, if there is anything you notice it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is this code running on server or local machine ? check your smtp and sendmail settings

Comment: @Pramod localhost, and I wasn't exactly sure how to set up the smtp and sendmail settings. I changed it in the php.ini files as shown in the question but I didn't know if I had done it right

Comment: I hav given you snippet below. Please do changes in php.ini with your email id and password.

Answer (score 0):

You can send email via localhost using gmail.   Do the setting php.ini for sendmail with your email id and password.

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com  
    smtp_port=25  
    error_logfile=error.log  
    debug_logfile=debug.log  
    auth_username=myemail@gmail.com 
    auth_password=gmailpassword
```

Note: After doing changes please restart your server.
        force_sender=myemail@gmail.com

Comment: these lines will there. it has commented . search in php.ini with smtp_server key word and uncomment the lines and set your own value like email and password

Comment: So this snippet goes in the php.ini file?

Comment: just above code put into php.ini if it does not exist in php.ini. if it is exist, just change the values of them.

Comment: Does it have to be a gmail?

Comment: if you want to send email from localhost then gmail allow us to send email. if you are testing on hosting server then respective email will taken place on gmail.